# Why Performance of PyQt5 QTableWidget Setitem Much Faster than PySide2?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, pyside2

I have a data with 1000 records showing in QTableWidget (13 columns), after refresh 4 times, I get setItem 52000 times, and using pycharm Profile method, the time for 52000 times is 84ms.
After PySide2 come out ( Qt for Python 5.11 mid May), I only change from "from PyQt5... import ..." to "from PySide2... import ..." for my program, the time for 52000 times is 3171ms. 
I know both PyQt5 and PySide2 depend on Qt5, but the performance shocked. I want to use PySide2 for future with LGPL, how can I fix it ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidgetItem, QMainWindow, QTableWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 300, 960, 540)
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.table.setRowCount(1000)
        self.horizontal_header = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                                  "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"]
        self.table.setColumnCount(len(self.horizontal_header))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.horizontal_header)
        for i in range(4):
            self._run()
        raise NameError

    def _run(self):
        for row in range(1000):
            for column in range(13):
                item = QTableWidgetItem('1')
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please provide some minimal, reproducable code for your problem. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: I've post my simple test code.

Comment: @dearfad. There is no point in reporting issues like this here. Use the [bug-tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/PYSIDE/issues/PYSIDE-431?filter=allopenissues).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you, I'm not sure if it's a bug, but I'd send my issue to bug-tracker.